# How the does YouTube SSL certificate work, it says *.google.com

Tags: ssl, youtube, certificate, wildcard

I was just wondering how the YouTube SSL certificate works because it says it was issued to *.google.com.

I thought wildcard SSL certificates would only work with sub domains?

Thanks in advance,
Francis

Comment: Voting to move to SU.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Common Name (CN) in the certificate is only used when no DNS Subject Alternative Names are present (see [RFC 2818 Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1)). When SANs are present, any of them is good for identifying the server. The certificate use by YouTube has all of these:

```
DNS Name: *.google.com
DNS Name: *.android.com
DNS Name: *.appengine.google.com
DNS Name: *.cloud.google.com
DNS Name: *.google-analytics.com
DNS Name: *.google.ca
DNS Name: *.google.cl
DNS Name: *.google.co.in
DNS Name: *.google.co.jp
DNS Name: *.google.co.uk
DNS Name: *.google.com.ar
DNS Name: *.google.com.au
DNS Name: *.google.com.br
DNS Name: *.google.com.co
DNS Name: *.google.com.mx
DNS Name: *.google.com.tr
DNS Name: *.google.com.vn
DNS Name: *.google.de
DNS Name: *.google.es
DNS Name: *.google.fr
DNS Name: *.google.hu
DNS Name: *.google.it
DNS Name: *.google.nl
DNS Name: *.google.pl
DNS Name: *.google.pt
DNS Name: *.googleapis.cn
DNS Name: *.googlecommerce.com
DNS Name: *.gstatic.com
DNS Name: *.urchin.com
DNS Name: *.url.google.com
DNS Name: *.youtube-nocookie.com
DNS Name: *.youtube.com
DNS Name: *.youtubeeducation.com
DNS Name: *.ytimg.com
DNS Name: android.com
DNS Name: g.co
DNS Name: goo.gl
DNS Name: google-analytics.com
DNS Name: google.com
DNS Name: googlecommerce.com
DNS Name: urchin.com
DNS Name: youtu.be
DNS Name: youtube.com
DNS Name: youtubeeducation.com
```